# Choosing a JS framework (switch from Mootools to Closure or Dojo)

Tags: javascript, frameworks, dojo, mootools, google-closure

The project I'm working on is a "framework" for a very specific type of b2b websites. Currently I got everything working on the iOS and on PC with almost any browser. It ships different layouts and code for different platforms, and everything works fine, but what I stucked in is a maintenance problem: I've got JS-modules for UI objects, layouts (so there is no problem running on both iPhone and PC with a FullHD resolution), ajax data and so on. Some modules are universal, some are platform dependant and I'd like to "compile" them in several packages, something like:

- iOS,
- any browser with Flash 10 (even IE6)
- IE9-Opera12-FF5-Safari on PC/Mac (Chrome lacks some features to my surprise)
- failsafe configuration (no Flash or JS)
- Android/WP7/Bada (not yet, but will be ready in two months)

Everything is written using Mootools. 90% of is code is unique, because almost any library I'd like to use failed to work on iOS or IE 6-8.

The problem is that Mootools doesn't work fine with Closue Compiler. I'm using gnu-make + google-closure-compiler + doxygen right now, then it got rpm'd and deployed on the server. It works, but I still can't get closure compiler working on advanced level (because of mootools' Class module, which I definetely need). The another problem is that I have to merge js and css files all by myself (the order is hardcoded in a makefile).

The question is, what should I choose:

- is it worth a try to rewrite all the code against Closure Library, to get Closure Compiler working fine (so I'll have minifying, some kind of obfuscation and finally get my scripts merged in one)
- continue using Mootools and try to use require.js+Rhino when compiling, like ACE(Cloud9) Editor for example
- choose Dojo, but I don't know anything about it, regarding conditional compiling, minifying and obfuscation
- other toolchain you know about

The last thing I'd like to mention, that I'd like to get an abstact Data model alongside, something like Data Package in ExtJs. But I need only "M" from "MVC", nothing more.

I'm happy with my backend and any serverside support is not an advantage for me.

Thx in advance.

Comment: Your question is not really clear to me: the title is about the choice of a *framework*, but you seem more concerned about choosing a *minifier*, aren't you? If you really have 90% of your code homemade, then switching to another framework simply because you can't get Closure as a compiler seems totally insane to me. What is so important about _Closure_ itself?

Comment: I need a reliable toolchain to continue my work. Make+GCC works fine, but GCC don't like Mootools Class function. I guess that Closure Library will work better with GCC, so it will handle advanced optimisations (so it will be some kind of obfuscation). Also I need some Data model abstaction level, that I have to write on my own with Mootools, but since it is not so browser dependant, I think of using other framework that already have it.

Comment: P.S. ExtJs+Sencha is an overkill for my purposes. 90% of code is homemade, but it is not so library dependent, so I can rewrite it easily now. But it won't be so easy later, so I need to make a decision right now.

Answer (score 4):

Another option: you can use Closure without advanced mode, and still get a lot of benefit.  That's what Dojo does OOTB.  Getting Closure working in advanced mode is tricky business with any library, as well as with your own code.  Dojo has a toolchain that will take care of a lot of minification/obfuscation/concatenation/etc. -- I don't know how the toolchain compares with mootools, but I'd imagine it's possible to optimize code in Mootools as well, even if you have to write a script or use some other tools to do so.  Changing toolkits just to make this happen doesn't make sense.   You'd probably have to rewrite a lot of code.  Changing/leveraging toolkits because you need new functionality is a different story, though you ought to be able to combine toolkits.  Many toolkits, including Dojo have MVC abstractions -- perhaps mootools does also.

Comment: Mootools is a library like a jQuery: it extends browser and engine objects a lot, but doesn't have any abstaction layers like the ExtJS do.

Comment: MooTools is not a library! It's a modular framework, jQuery is a library.

Comment: MooTools is a library, jquery is a DSL + ajax toolkit.

Comment: I disagree. I wanted to point out that a library is a 'generic' way to call a toolkit (basically, a set of defined functions..like jQ). Framework instead involves an 'abstract' layer (see also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control) thought to be used/extended and can also act like a skeleton, like MooTools.

Comment: I use Mootools a lot and I still think of it as just a library. ExtJs or Backbone are the real frameworks.

Comment: agree. Class gives you something to build on which can allow you to structure, but mootools really is like the middleware of js libs. http://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-a-JavaScript-framework-and-a-library/answer/Tom-Robinson